# Prove that $\omega(r) \leq (\frac{r}{R})^\alpha \omega(R)$

Tags: real-analysis

This is a step in the proof of the scilation lemma in Regularity Theory:

Let $\omega:(0,R) \to \mathbb{R}$ be an increasing function. For $\tau, c \in (0,1)$ and for all $0<r<R$ it satisfies $$\omega(\tau r) \leq c \omega(r)$$

Show that there exists $\alpha = \alpha(c,\tau) >0$ such that $$\omega(r) \leq \Big (\frac{r}{R} \Big )^\alpha \omega(R).$$

I have tried a proof by contradiction, i.e. for all $\alpha$ the opposite inequality holds. But no success so far. Any help is appreciated.

Edit 1 ------------

Here is an attempt:

Let $0< r'< R$, and pick $c = \frac{r'}{R}$. Then,

$$\omega(\tau r') \leq \frac{r'}{R} \omega(r').$$ thus, for $0<r \leq \tau r' < r' < R$ by the fact that $\omega$ is increasing we obtain

$$\omega(r) \leq \frac{r'}{R} \omega(R)$$ which is not really what we want, but it is as close as I got.

Edit 2 ---------

I have realized that if I write the first inequality as $\omega( \tau R) \leq c\omega(R)$ then the problem is done as soon as I choose $\tau = \frac{r}{R}$ and $\alpha$ such that $\tau^\alpha = c$. The problem is that by assumption, $\omega$ is defined only on $(0,R)$ and I have no assumptions on its continuity on $(0,R]$

Comment: How is $\omega(R)$ even defined if the domain of $\omega$ is $(0,R)$?

Comment: I had the same question! I asked my professor today and he said it was a typo. So the interval of definition of $\omega$ is $(0,R]$

Comment: What is the meaning of "For $\tau, c \in (0,1)$" in the statement? For *all*  $\tau, c$ or just for one given pair $\tau, c$?